# show that $A^{\perp} = (\overline{A})^{\perp} $

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, orthogonality

A is a non-empty subset of a pre-Hilbert space

and I'm asked to show that the orthogonal complement of A is equal to the orthogonal complement of its closure.

I solved it in a different way than what the solution of the textbook suggests so I'm just asking for confirmation if my approach is correct or not

what I've done :

since $A \subset \overline{A}$ then  $(\overline{A})^{\perp} \subset A^{\perp} $

let $a \in A^{\perp}$, $l \in \overline{A} $

there exists a sequence of elements of $A$ that converges to $l$ which means $l = \lim_{n\to{+\infty}}x_n $

I'll use the property of continuity of the inner product in the right slot

$$ \lt a , l\gt = \lt a, \lim_{n\to{+\infty}}x_n \gt = \lim_{n\to{+\infty}}\lt a,x_n \gt= \lim_{n\to{+\infty}}0=0$$

therefore both sets are equal

is everything fine ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's basically the proof I would have given as well. The stated continuity should either be proved as a lemma (from Cauchy -Schwartz) or maybe this has been done beforehand in your text). I also assume that it is known (in your educational context) that a point is in $\overline{A}$ (in a metric space) iff there is a sequence from $A$ converging to it. With these caveats in mind, I agree with the proof.

One remark on exposition: maybe you could state the goals more explicitly: Let $a \in A^\perp$, we want to show that $a \in \overline{A}^\perp$, so let $l \in \overline{A}$ and we'll show that $\langle a,l\rangle = 0$. Then pick the sequence etc. and do the rest of the argument.